# How do you sort a list in python by comparing it to a separate list?

Tags: python

so let's say I have a list:

```
A = [cat, dog, mouse, horse, bird, rabbit]
```

that will be used as the reference list, and another list:

```
B = [dog, rabbit, horse, bird, cat, dog]
```

that has the exact same elements as the reference list but in a different order. 
I want to sort list B the exact same order as list A, so what I tried was:

```
for indexA in range(0, len(A)):
    for indexB in range(0, len(B)):
        if A[indexA] == B[indexB]:
            B[indexA], B[indexB] = B[indexB], B[indexA]
```

but that doesn't quite work...
What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: turn A into a dictionary with integer number, use that to sort B.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski i think OP didn't state it well. what OP wants to do is let A act as a ordering base, and the elements in B all definitely come from A but now OP wants them in the order of A.

Comment: Well...pedantically speaking...if B `has the exact same elements` as the reference list, then: `B=A[:]` should work!

Comment: Pursuant to discussion on another question: the now-linked duplicate seems like a better phrasing of the question. Showing an attempt at manual bubble sort does not help clarify the question very much, and the example inputs seem not as good for clarifying the intended behaviour (also, the desired result wasn't explicitly stated here).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sort` or `sorted` with the `key` to use `A.index` of the current word.

```
>>> sorted(B, key = A.index)
['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'horse', 'bird', 'rabbit']
```

Answer (score 5):

Not that algorithmic complexity matters for such small lists, but you can avoid Omega(n*m):

```
ranks = dict((value, idx) for idx, value in enumerate(A))
B.sort(key = ranks.get)
```

A more concise way to write the first line is:

```
ranks = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(A)))
```

... but I can't decide whether that's too tricksy for public consumption!

Comment: There's no need for anything this complex. The built-in sort will only apply the `key` function once for each element of the input, caching results.

Comment: Oh, wait. I see. The concern is about the complexity of the `.index` operation applied multiple times (performing linear search).