# Rearranging list based on order of another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am sure this question has possibly been asked before but I can't seem to find the correct answer. If I have two lists

```
_list1 = ["keyName", "test1", "test2"]
_list2 = ["keyName", "test2", "test1"]
```

I am trying to use _list1 to rearrange elements in _list2 so that they match the order exactly. What's the cleanest way to do that? Desired output:

```
_list1 = ["keyName", "test1", "test2"]
_list2 = ["keyName", "test1", "test2"]
```

I am sorry if this is duplicate but so far I am only able to find answers for list of numbers and using zipped sorted() method.

What if the _list2 is a list of lists?

```
_list2 = [["test1", "test2", "keyName"], ["test2", "test1", "keyName"]]
```

Desired Output:

```
_list2 = [["keyName", "test1", "test2"], ["keyName", "test1", "test2"]]
```

One more what if: What if I wanted to sort any other list of objects using _list1 as a key

```
_list2 = [[object1, object2, object3], [object1, object2, object3]]
```

where:

```
object1.Name = "keyName"
object3.Name = "test1"
object2.Name = "test2"
```

so effectively I would expect output of:

```
_list2 = [[object1, object3, objec1], [object1, object3, objec1]]
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Are both of the list is going to have same values exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you sort a list in python by comparing it to a separate list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573420/how-do-you-sort-a-list-in-python-by-comparing-it-to-a-separate-list)

Comment: yes, they will all have the same string values. One more caveat though its possible that _list2 will be a nested list of lists that will contain lists of the same string values like so _list2=[["test1", "keyName","test2"]["test2", "test1", "keyName"]]. So the values always are going to be the same its just that sometimes the structure of _list2 might change

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In [84]: _list1 = ["keyName", "test1", "test2"]

In [85]: d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(_list1)}

In [86]: _list2 = ["keyName", "test2", "test1"]

In [87]: _list2.sort(key=d.get)

In [88]: _list2
Out[88]: ['keyName', 'test1', 'test2']
```

Comment: using dict it will be faster, as get has O(1) where as index has O(n). GOOD :)

Answer (score 16):

try to use key with sorted:

```
sorted(_list2,key=_list1.index)
```

for nested list you can use list comphresnion:

```
[sorted(x,key=_lis1.index) for x in _list2]
```

Comment: `sorted()` does not work if there are elements in list2 that do not exist in list 1

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers do work when the list used for sorting does contain the same key values. If this is not the case this function could help:
It will add all missing values to the end of the sorted list.

```
def sort_list(order, list_to_order):
    i=len(order) 
    sorted_list= [None] * (len(list_to_order)+(len(order)))
    for value in list_to_order:
       try: 
           idx = order.index(value)
           sorted_list[idx]= value
       except ValueError: #value not found in the list
           sorted_list[i]= value
           i=i+1
    return [x for x in sorted_list if x!=None]
```