# sort two lists with different length by nested index

Tags: python, list

my question is quite similar as this one: 
[Rearranging list based on order of another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725703/rearranging-list-based-on-order-of-another-list)

I have two lists, inside the list there are tuples, I want them to be order by the first element in the tuple * even if the length is not equal or if the items are different.

```
_list1 = [
 ('CLINIQUE Lash', 'https://ww', '$25.00', 'Lash Power'),
 ('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', 'https://default/_240__1.jpg', '$28.90', 'LEONIDAS'), 
 ('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', 'http', '$5.00', 'TWIX'),
 ('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml', 'https:jpg', '$105.00', 'Chocolate Greedy'),
 ('Valrhona Equinoxe Almods & Hazelnuts Dark Chocolate Gift Box 125 Gr', '_47170.jpg', '$14.90', 'VALRHONA') ]

_list2 = [
 ('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', 'ht9/1944__1944.jpg', '$5.00', 'TWIX'),
 ('something else', '44127__44129.jpg', '$25.00', 'Lash Power'),
 ('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', 'h_240__1.jpg', '$28.90', 'LEONIDAS'),
 ('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml', 'http/36344__36346.jpg', '$105.00', 'Chocolate Greedy') ]
```

expected output:

```
_list1 = [
 ('CLINIQUE Lash', 'https://ww', '$25.00', 'Lash Power'),
 ('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', 'https://default/_240__1.jpg', '$28.90', 'LEONIDAS'), 
 ('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', 'http', '$5.00', 'TWIX'),
 ('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml', 'https:jpg', '$105.00', 'Chocolate Greedy'),
 ('Valrhona Equinoxe Almods & Hazelnuts Dark Chocolate Gift Box 125 Gr', '_47170.jpg', '$14.90', 'VALRHONA') ]

_list2 = [
 ('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', 'h_240__1.jpg', '$28.90', 'LEONIDAS'),
 ('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', 'ht9/1944__1944.jpg', '$5.00', 'TWIX'),
 ('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml', 'http/36344__36346.jpg', '$105.00', 'Chocolate Greedy'),
 ('something else', '44127__44129.jpg', '$25.00', 'Lash Power')]
```

Comment: How do you decide where to put `('something else', '44127__44129.jpg', '$25.00', 'Lash Power')` in your sorted list ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In what order do you want it sorted? I see Twix before Montale, I would think that would be the opposite. Should only `_list2` be sorted?

Comment: i think the best algorithm is: if items show in both lists put them at top, if not, do not do anything..

Comment: i want _list2 will be order by _list1

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `dict` to store the index and the first element from the `_list1` tuples and base on this to sort your `_lsit2` inline:

```
item_idx = {t[0]: i for i, t in enumerate(_list1)}
# make sure to send to the end of the list the items that are not in list 1 tuples first position
max_value = len(_list1)
_list2.sort(key=lambda t: item_idx.get(t[0], max_value))
```

if you print `_list2`/ output:

```
[('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', 'h_240__1.jpg', '$28.90', 'LEONIDAS'),
 ('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', 'ht9/1944__1944.jpg', '$5.00', 'TWIX'),
 ('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml',
  'http/36344__36346.jpg',
  '$105.00',
  'Chocolate Greedy'),
 ('something else', '44127__44129.jpg', '$25.00', 'Lash Power')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
def secondsort(list1, list2):
    ''' Given two lists of tuples returns the second list
        sorted on the first item in the tuple in the same
        order as the first tuple item in the first list.
        What to do in case of duplicate keys isn't defined.
        Sort on second tuple item? Keep existing order in list?
    '''
    # Create set of keys for both lists. Use "set" to minimize
    # sort space in case of really long lists with duplicates.
    # Certainly overkill.
    d1 = set(i[0] for i in list1)
    d2 = set(i[0] for i in list2)
    # Return a concatenation of two lists. The first is a all the
    # items in `list1` that have keys in `list2`. The second contains
    # the items of in `list1` that do NOT have keys in `list2`.
    return ([row for row in list1 if row[0] in d2] + 
            [row for row in list2 if row[0] not in d1])
```

Output:

```
[('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', 'https://default/_240__1.jpg', '$28.90', 'LEONIDAS'),
 ('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', 'http', '$5.00', 'TWIX'),
 ('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml', 'https:jpg', '$105.00', 'Chocolate Greedy'),
 ('something else', '44127__44129.jpg', '$25.00', 'Lash Power')]
```

Comment: what to do if you have two of the same keys is not defined.

Comment: It wasn't specified that all values in the list are unique so the assumption should ideally be that it isn't.

Comment: I disagree. The list data structure by itself allows duplicates. Therefore, the direct implication is that there can be duplicates. If the OP wanted unique values, either it should have been explicitly stated or a set would have been used to imply that it is a data structure of unique values.

Comment: shrug. i don't see where the OP as said what to do if there are duplicates so i see it as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

alright I've got something but I would like to hear about another way:)

```
s_l1, s_l2 = [], []

for item1 in _list1:
    for item2 in _list2:
        if(item1[0] == item2[0]):
            s_l1.append(item1)
            s_l2.append(item2)


for item in _list1:
    if item not in s_l1:
        s_l1.append(item)
for item in _list2:
    if item not in s_l2:
        s_l2.append(item)
```

Comment: iterators are your friend. whenever you see a trivial 'for' loop especially with an 'append,' think "how do i turn this into an iterator.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice, I wrote it in something like 5 minute so i might hurry

Comment: this is very inefficient, you have 4 `for` loops,

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that's commented to explain the logic along the way.

FYI, in the example data, I removed the extraneous tuple entries from the input data, since they aren't relevant to the sorting logic.

```
def sort_by_list(to_sort, sort_by):
    # Map sort_by first element values to their index.
    sort_by_index = {v[0]: i for i, v in enumerate(sort_by)}

    # Create a list which will contain the final sorting result.
    result = []

    # Create a temporary list of values not in sort_by.
    not_in_sort_by = []

    # Populate both lists.
    for v in to_sort:
        if v[0] in sort_by_index:
            result.append(v)
        else:
            not_in_sort_by.append(v)

    # result contains only values found in sort_by. Sort them
    # by the their location in the sort_by list.
    result.sort(key=lambda v: sort_by_index.get(v[0]))

    # Sort the remaining values.
    # (Skip this if you don't care about the order of the leftover items.)
    not_in_sort_by.sort()

    # Extend the results with the sorted remaining values.
    result.extend(not_in_sort_by)

    return result

_list1 = [
    ('CLINIQUE Lash', '...'),
    ('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', '...'),
    ('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', '...'),
    ('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml', '...'),
    ('Valrhona Equinoxe Almods & Hazelnuts Dark Chocolate Gift Box 125 Gr',
     '...'),
]

_list2 = [
    ('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', '...'),
    ('something else', '...'),
    ('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', '...'),
    ('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml', '...'),
]

for v in sort_by_list(_list2, _list1):
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 sort_by_first_list.py
('LEONIDAS Premium Chocolate 245GR', '...')
('Twix Chocolate 6x50 Gr', '...')
('Montale Chocolate Greedy Edp 100ml', '...')
('something else', '...')
```

Comment: why are you converting the index in str here: `str(sort_by_index.get(v[0]))` ?in this way  the element form position 2 will be grather than the one from position 10 since '2' > '10' or '1000000'

Comment: your solution will not work if _list 1 has more than 9 elements

Comment: and why are you sorting the elements from not_in_sort_by list : `not_in_sort_by.sort()` ?

Comment: Regarding the first comment, that was an accidental leftover from experimenting with trying to do all the sorting at once. Removed.

Comment: Regarding sorting not_in_sort_by, the intention was to point out the opportunity to sort the "leftovers" (if desired, as the comment calls out). Since the data only has a single "leftover", I wasn't able to infer the intended behavior. So, I decided to demonstrate the optional step.