# How can I enumerate a list of objects in python according to a specific order

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a list of objects that may be strings or arbitrary numbers that may be repeating e.g.:

```
x = ['id1', 'id5', 'id3', 'id1', 'id4', 'id5', 'id2', 'id3']
```

and a universal ordering of all the possible values in that list

```
x_ordered = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5']
```

How can I get a list of similar length to x but with the indexes of `x_ordered` in place of the actual values like:

```
y = ???(x, x_ordered)
>>> y = [0, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Is there something that does this in `numpy` for example?

I don't want to have to do a python for-loop where I search the position of the value on every iteration. There's got to be something vectorized.

Comment: You could use this: `[x_ordered.index(z) for z in x]` - of course, you want vectorized, though.

Comment: @user17242583 you *could* but you *shouldn't* because that's quadratic time

Comment: Another option I am thinking would be creating a dictionary from values to index and using that with `map` to avoid the exhaustive search for every element. But I wanted to ask if there is a function I am not aware of that does this already.

Comment: Fist, create a mapping from value to index, `keymap = {value: index for index, value in enumerate(x_ordered)}` Then use `sorted(x, key=keymap.get)`

Comment: Note, the highest voted answer in the linked duplicate is *inefficient*, use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27725767/5014455) which takes the same approach as I described above

Comment: @Michael no, there is no pre-existing function (other than using `sorted` or `list.sort`, of course). But you described a good algorithm for generating an effective key function.

Comment: "There's got to be something vectorized." *vectorized approaches would use a loop to find every element, and would be similarly inefficient! Vectorization with lowers constant factors, usually significantly, but it doesn't necessarily change the algorithmic complexity!

Comment: Ok, thanks I went with the dictionary approach.

Comment: In the `numpy` context `vectorized` just means using compiled numpy methods.  It may still do iteration, but in faster compiled code.  It's not a catch all term for "do something faster/smarter".  This a 'grouping' task that, other than `bincount` has not been implemented as a compiled method.