# How to sort a list of tuples according to the order of a tuple element in another list?

Tags: python, list

```
list_1 = [2, 7, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 8, 9]
list_2 = [(1, 5), (2, 0), (3, 6), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 1), (8, 7), (9, 8)]
```

I want to reorder list `list_2` such that the first element of each tuple follows the order specified by `list_1`, so:

```
list_2_ordered = [(2, 0), (7, 1), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (1, 5), (3, 6), (8, 7), (9, 8)]
```

I try to use the `map` function to map `filter` over the `list_1` as iterables (the general idea `map(filter(lambda x,j : x[0]==j, list_2),list_1)`. But of course it doesn't work (I think due to type error). How can I do this with the least number of code lines?

Comment: "I want to reorder " Okay, so you want the built-in `sorted`. "follows the order specified by" Okay, so you use the `key` argument for `sorted`. ` by list 1 so` I.e., by its *position within* list 1, which is given by the `.index` method on that list. Read the documentation, and the solution drops out. "I try to use the map function to map filter over the list_1 as iterables" **This doesn't make any sense**. `filter` is for removing things, not reordering them; and it already processes an entire sequence. `map` is for applying a *single-element function* to a sequence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rearranging list based on order of another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725703/rearranging-list-based-on-order-of-another-list). The only difference is you need to get the first tuple element: `key=lambda t: <function>(t[0])`

Comment: `[list_2[i-1] for i in list_1]`???

Answer (score 4):

Craft a dictionary to map your sorting order (the key being your number and the value the order in list_1) and use `sorted` with a custom `key` that will map the first item to the dictionary (and thus the expected order):

```py
order = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(list_1)}
list_2_ordered = sorted(list_2, key=lambda x: order.get(x[0], float('inf')))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 0), (7, 1), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (1, 5), (3, 6), (8, 7), (9, 8)]
```

*NB. I used `order.get` with `float('inf')` as second parameter to handle the case where the first item is not present in `order`. In this case, the tuple will be sorted at the end. If you use `-1` as default value, this will sort the unknown keys at the beginning*

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to get your desired outcome in two steps:

(i) Create dictionary `dic1` to lookup the position of each item in `list1`

(ii) Sort `list_2` by the first elements using their positions in `list_1` with dictionary `dic1`

```py
dic1 = {k:v for k,v in zip(list_1, range(len(list_1)))}
list_2.sort(key = lambda x: dic1[x[0]])
print(list_2)
```

Output:

```
[(2, 0), (7, 1), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (1, 5), (3, 6), (8, 7), (9, 8)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in the fewest lines of code:

```py
>>> list_2.sort(key=lambda t: list_1.index(t[0]))
>>> list_2
[(2, 0), (7, 1), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (1, 5), (3, 6), (8, 7), (9, 8)]
```

Other solutions here that involve creating a dict are more efficient for large lists (that `index` call is O(n) so it takes the sort from O(n log n) to O(n^2)), but for a small list like this, the difference is likely to be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

The `key` you need is even simpler than represented by the other answers.

`list1.index(a)` tells you the position of `a` within `list1`, if applicable. You want to sort the `x`s found in your `list2` according to (i.e., `key`ed by) the position of `x[0]` within `list1`, i.e., according to `list1.index(x[0])` (and all of our `x[0]` values are indeed `in list1`, so there is no potential exception); `x` is a `lambda` parameter (i.e., a name that we used in the previous sentence in order to explain the rule), so we have our `key=lambda x: list1.index(x[0])`; we want to `.sort` our `list2` with that `key`, so we write it directly:

```
list_2.sort(key=lambda x: list1.index(x[0]))
```

No need to build anything else.

Comment: The dictionary allows one pass on the list (ok two counting the dict creation), while your approach would basically be `o(n**2)` (iterating the list for each item in it...)

Comment: No; I am presuming here that `list1` is a constant-length (and small) list enumerating all the possibilities for `x[0]` values, and that this does not increase for a larger `list2`.

Comment: Fair enough. That would still technically be `O(n*m)` where `n` and `m` being the sizes of the lists. Would be interesting to measure what the actual impact is...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a "key" function to the lists sort function in python. This determines the order of the sorted list!

```py
list_2.sort(key=lambda x: list_1.index(x[0]))
print(list_2)
```