# Sorting a short list according to the order of a longer list

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

Suppose I have a reference list:

```
A = ['X_0', 'Z_0', 'X_1', 'Y_0', 'Z_1', 'X_2', 'Y_1', 'Z_2', 'Y_2']
```

as well as an (example) shorter list:

```
B = ['Z_0', 'X_1', 'X_0']
```

How can I sort `B` so that the order of the elements match the order provided in `A`? The final results should thus match the order of `A` like so:

```
B_final = ['X_0', 'Z_0', 'X_1']
```

Comment: Something like `sorted(B, key=A.index)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27573462/12671057

Comment: @KellyBundy pursuant to the investigation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74396615, I have saved this as canonical for now. I really hope it would be possible to find something more popular for a problem that I know I see asked about all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the list B sorted by the index of the value in A, so;

```
sorted(B, key=A.index)
```

This will sort B by each values index in A.

If you are using a very long list, index is not very efficient since it searches the list for every value, so you may want to go for sorting by a dictionary instead.

First create a dictionary of the index values of the list;

```
>>> C = {val:ix for ix,val in enumerate(A)}
```

...then sort by the dictionary value, which is much more efficient than a linear search in the list;

```
>>> sorted(B, key=C.get)
['X_0', 'Z_0', 'X_1']
```

Comment: In case there are duplicates in `A`, iterating in reverse order instead would use the earliest index for each value.